# SDWebImage changing images while tableview scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sdwebimage

There is a TableView with Cells and there is ImageView in each of them.
I use SDWebImage to load images and it works fine, but when I scroll fast - I see that images in cells are changing few times before it will be right image.

Why is it happening? What should I do?

p.s. I tried use it with  or without placeholder with same result

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string : myImageURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "default.jpg"))
```

Answer (score 5):

In your prepareForReuse() try adding:

```
imageView.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
```

It will cancel the previous image downloading and then it won't happen.

Also, I would suggest using the sd_setImage with the completion block, that way you can also make sure it loads correctly.

Comment: What can you recommend to check in this completion block?

Comment: usually I add a fade animation to make the image appear more smoothly, when you add a fade-in transition to the image, users don't notice when you have hard image transitions, sometimes I also checked if the image matches the object (object was cleared upon a private initializer in the cell itself). But also SDWebImage's method with completion block works better.

Answer (score 4):

```
// This will prevent sdwebimage load wrong url
guard let imgUrl = "Your image url.jpg" else { return }
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imgUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Your placeholder image.png"))


// Or you can match the url using this code, so the downloader won't catch the wrong url
if imgUrl == "Your image url" {
    imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imgUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Your placeholder image.png"))
}


// This is will clean your UIImageView, and cancel download progress when cell is not visible (will reuse)
class YourCell: UITableViewCell {
    override prepareForReuse() {
        imageView.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
        imageView.image = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: You better add this as comment - not an answer

Comment: @moonvader hei is my Answer solved your problem? if yes please upvote, if not, please upvote too, because i already provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can use placeholder image of `SDWebImage`.

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Secondly, you can clean image when cell was reused.

```
class YourCell: UITableViewCell {
    override prepareForReuse() {
        // sample code
        imageView.image = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to combine both methods that you suggest, but when I scroll fast - I still see that images are changing few times

Comment: @moonvader I wonder how many times did you set the image for one cell.

Comment: In cellForRowAt of my table I run function getImage(imageView: cell.ImageView, item_id: id) it takes imageview and id of item that it should find image for, after this it uses sd_setImage to load image to this imageview

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell
```

Instead of

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! NewsTableViewCell
```

Hope it will solve Your problem. It is repeating because of reusability of Cell

Comment: While your diagnosis is correct, this is not a solution to the problem. Cell reuse is a great optimisation technique so you should instead try to work with it, not around it.